# How would I selectively print a set of named ranges in Excel based on a criteria in a cell

Tags: excel, range, named

I have a set of named ranges that I want to print but only if a cell value is greater than 1 if cell value = 0 then the code needs to ignore that range and not print it at all.

I have no idea where to even start.

Answer (score 0):

After you defined in your macro the ranges which should be printed can use the PrintOut method. This is a method of the Range object. Detailed info can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office2000/aa273969(v=office.10)). (Microsoft site)